# scrollvisible is not working in barebone code

Tags: codenameone

If I check the ScrollVisible from theme, the scrollbar is hidden. But I am using barebone code, so I have no GUI form. That is why I used f.setScrollVisible(false);, but it has no effect. How can I remove the scroll bar from code?

Also if I want to implement the hidden scrollbar in all the forms of my apps, how can I do that?

```
public void init(Object context) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `setScrollVisible` you need to do this on the actual scrollable container e.g.:

```
f.getContentPane().setScrollVisible(false);
```

You can style the `Scroll` and `ScrollThumb` UIID any way you like to make them completely transparent.